# Finding x when the exponents and coefficients are different

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I find $x$ when the exponents and coefficients are different?

$$3x \cdot e^{7x+2} = 15$$

Thanks

Comment: Multiply both sides of the equation by $\frac{7}{3}$ and then solve with respect to $y=7x$.

Comment: $x$ can only be determined numerically or by using Lambert's function.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy: And how would you solve such a transcendental equation (probably at an elementary level)? No, this one does not have a simple solution.

Comment: @AlexM. I never said it had a simple solution. As @ Peter already mentioned, the Lambert's W-function is a way to go (or use numerical methods).

Answer (score 1):

When the variable you are solving for appears in both the exponent and as a coefficient, solving using the [Lambert W Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) is recommended.  To use the Lambert W Function, both coefficient and exponent must be the same and the base of the exponent must be $e$, Euler's number.

In other words, it must look like $ye^y=x$  It would then have the solution $y=W(x)$

$3xe^{7x+2}=15$

Divide by $e^2$ because it is difficult to solve most of these types of problems when extra numbers are being added in the exponent.

$3xe^{7x}=\frac{15}{e^2}=15e^{-2}$

Then multiply both sides of the equation by $\frac{7}{3}$ so that it becomes in the format of $ye^y=x$.

$7xe^{7x}=35e^{-2}$

You then take "W's" of both sides to solve.

$7x=W(35e^{-2})$

And then divide by 7.

$x=\frac{W(35e^{-2})}{7}$

As to a decimal value for the solution, there are Lambert W calculators that you can find online:  http://www.had2know.com/academics/lambert-w-function-calculator.html

Using this calculator...

$x\approx0.185148143$

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the [Lambert W Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), we have 
$$3xe^{7x+2}=15\implies 7xe^{7x}=35e^{-2}\implies x=\frac17 W\left(35e^{-2}\right)$$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  - Mark